# Check the content of an array -- CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I query a CosmosDB database using the following query :

```
SELECT c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail FROM c 
WHERE (c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.subdomain = '137'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.domain = '26'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.type = '3')
```

I get as a response

```
[
    {
        "EndDeviceEventDetail": [
            {
                "name": "Spontaneous",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "name": "DetectionActive",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "name": "RCDSwitchReleased",
                "value": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EndDeviceEventDetail": [
            {
                "name": "Spontaneous",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "name": "DetectionActive",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "name": "RCDSwitchReleased",
                "value": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to get as step further and modify my query so that I get a response only if "RCDSwitchReleased" is true.

I naïvely tried without success :

```
SELECT c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail FROM c 
WHERE (c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.subdomain = '137'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.domain = '26'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.type = '3')
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail[2].value = 'true'
```

but I get a BadRequest (400) error message.
Any direction/help to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue with `Value` Keyword. Cosmos SQL use [Value Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#ValueKeyword) in many different ways, this is might be a reason, we can't use value field in select query.

I Changed the document with `value1` instead `value` then your query is working.

**Suggestion**

If you are applying a filter in the array, Always use [Array_Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-reference#bk_array_contains). If order of value inside your array `EndDeviceEventDetail` would change, your query will not return the correct result.

**My query**

```
SELECT c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail FROM c 
WHERE c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.subdomain = '137'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.domain = '26'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.type = '3'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail,{"name": 
"RCDSwitchReleased","value1": "true" })
```

**Query Output**

```
[
{
    "EndDeviceEventDetail": [
        {
            "name": "Spontaneous",
            "value1": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "DetectionActive",
            "value1": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "RCDSwitchReleased",
            "value1": "true"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: This is very useful and works like a charm. Thanks for sharing your expertise Pankaj.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question : how to return **only** the "value" of the array entry that contains the "name" "DetectionActive" ? Instead of returning as today the whole array.

I tried sthg under (but returned a boolean) but seems that I might need some kind of JOIN here ? 

`
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.EndDeviceEvent.Payload.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail,{'name':'DetectionActive' }) FROM c ...etc...
`

Comment: I made a new question for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145931/return-the-content-of-a-specific-object-in-an-array-cosmosdb

Comment: Let me check this question