# Return the content of a specific object in an array — CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This is a follow up to question [56126817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126817/check-the-content-of-an-array-cosmosdb)

### My current query

```
SELECT c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail FROM c 
WHERE c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.subdomain = '137'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.domain = '26'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.type = '3'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail,{"name": 
"RCDSwitchReleased","value": "true" })
```

### My Query Output

```
[
{
    "EndDeviceEventDetail": [
        {
            "name": "Spontaneous",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "DetectionActive",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "RCDSwitchReleased",
            "value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

### Question

How could change my query so that I select **only** the "value" of the array that contains the "name" "DetectionActive" ?
The idea behind is to filter the query on one array entry and get as output the "value" of another array entry. From reading here, UDF (not the best in this case) and JOIN should be used.

### First attempt

```
SELECT t.value FROM c JOIN t in c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail 
WHERE c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.subdomain = '137'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.domain = '26'
AND c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.type = '3'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail,{"name": 
"RCDSwitchReleased","value": "true" })
```

Gets Bad Request (400) error

Comment: Looks like you posted this question twice, the first being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126817/check-the-content-of-an-array-cosmosdb). Curious as to why. Please don't repeat the same question.

Comment: This question (Return the content of a specific object in an array — CosmosDB) is a bit different from the one you refered as original, so thought it was more appropriate to post a follow up question. It is not recommended to post follow up questions in the comment field (as I did in the original post).

Comment: Looks like the exact same root-cause: using a reserved word in the query (which both answers call out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea and direction is right absolutely, I simplified and tested your sql.

```
SELECT detail.value  FROM c 
join detail in c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail
WHERE c.EventType.EndDeviceEventType.eventOrAction = '93'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.EventType.EndDeviceEventDetail,{"name": 
"RCDSwitchReleased","value": "true" })
```

Found the error message as below:

[image]

It because that the `value` is the reserved word in cosmos db sql syntax,please refer to this case:[Using reserved word field name in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849310/using-reserved-word-field-name-in-documentdb)

You could try to modify the sql like:

```
SELECT detail["value"]  FROM c
```

Comment: This should have been marked as a duplicate of the question (and answer) you referred to. There are actually more than one question (and answer) dealing with reserved keywords as property names, with slightly different context.